# About type in application form

Tags: meaning

In the application form it says print or type. If we want to type do we need to type in capital letter or just by usual way(small and capital as necessary). Thank you.

Comment: NO NEED TO TYPE IN ALL CAPS.

Comment: When filling out forms by hand, it is best to print in Sᴍᴀʟʟ Cᴀᴘɪᴛᴀʟꜱ using Fᴜʟʟ Cᴀᴘꜱ instead of ꜱᴍᴀʟʟ ᴏɴᴇꜱ for things that should be Cᴀᴘɪᴛᴀʟɪᴢᴇᴅ. It is much much easier to read this way.

Comment: You should ask the people who sent you the form. They will be able to guide better than we can.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to type in all capitals unless specified by the form.  The one reason I can think of to use caps is if the fields have a separate box for each letter, but even then it is a question of style unless dictated.

Comment: When printing by hand, using only capitals (but both small and large ones) makes it supermorely easier to read.

Comment: Many countries follow the convention of typing the family name/surname ALL CAPS, e.g., NINJA Cornbread. I note that my information on my driver's license is all caps, as it was on my (dependent's) military ID card; maybe it's in some government style guide?

Answer (score 0):

If the application form doesn't specify (capital or not), you are free to choose any (or both). Though, in hand written forms, **capitals** are preferred as they are *more legible*. 
But it doesn't matter for a **printed/typed** forms, as the text is completely *legible*.